# How do you fix Netbeans hangs & doesnot allow creating new project bug, details in description

Tags: java, netbeans-7.3

I am unable to create new projects after a fresh installation of netbeans 7.3.1, I see many people have reported this issue but am not able to find a fix, what is missing, do i have a wrong java version in place?

> OS - Ubuntu 12.o4 LTS,
>
> Netbeans IDE - 7.3.1, same problem with the version you get using ubuntu software center,
>
> java version "1.6.0_27"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Issue/show stopper - on New project window --> choose Project --> categories - now nothing happens there is a wait cursor and thats all - all the remaining buttons except cancel are disabled and blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a the java 1.7 from oracle.
Then point your /etc/netbeans.conf "netbeans_jdkhome" to this location.

Comment: yes, i could make it work using java from oracle